# sed command between quotes

Tags: bash, jenkins, sed

Here is what I am trying to run the command against:

```
tags:
  - "environment:qa4"
```

I'm using the following command:

```
sed -e "s,"environment:[^/,"]*/,"environment:qa1,"" test.yaml
```

But it cuts off the closing quote:

```
tags:
  - "environment:qa1
```

I will be transferring this command over to Jenkins once i get it to work on the command line. How can I get it to pick the closing quote?

Thanks!

Comment: @Quasímodo sir this one works! does it need the "/" in the command? sed -e 's,"environment:[^,"]*,"environment:qa1,' test.yaml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean

```
sed -e 's,"environment:[^"]*","environment:qa1",' test.yaml
```

Notice that the outer quotes were changed to single-quotes, so that the double-quotes inside the pattern and substitution string are correctly interpreted literally.

Comment: sir this one works! does it need the "/" in the command? sed -e 's,"environment:[^,"]*,"environment:qa1,' test.yaml

Comment: @Lgalan90 No, in fact I didn't even realize you had put it there. Is there any reason to keep the comma as well (in `[^,"]`)? I think not.

Comment: It's odd that it works either way but thank you very much for your time!

Comment: You're welcome! But it's not odd, `[^/,"]` means [ not a slash, comma or double-quote ]. Then I think the best way is to simply make it `[^"]`. I'm updating with that.